# IPhone X - Adjusting view based on keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, keyboard, constraints

I'm currently trying to adjust the origin.y of a view based on when the keyboard shows/hides. I am able to adjust it accordingly however, on the iPhone X the contents of my adjusted view appears behind the status bar?

Below is the code for adjusting the view;

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if keyboardShown == false{
            self.containerView.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
            keyboardShown = true
            print("Keyboard UP")
        }
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if keyboardShown == true{
            self.containerView.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
            keyboardShown = false
            print("Keyboard DOWN")
        }
    }
```

They operated as intended minus the fact that the contents appears behind the statusbar (and is visible - overlapping with the time and signalbars etc.)

Below are screenshots to give a visual representation:

[image: Keyboard Hidden]

[image: Keyboard Shown]

I am using **Safe Area** in the Interface builder, and have constrained my UIElements in accordance to the Safe Area. However, the container view (everything beside the custom navigation bar) seem to move beyond the Safe Area when adjusting the view.frame.origin.y.

Is there a way to take into consideration the Safe Area programatically when manipulating views?

Comment: Absolutely, what do you want to know precisely, the length of a safe area?

Comment: I guess if I'm planning to move the view up in accordance to the height of the keyboard, is there a way to have a limitation to where the view can present itself to? I.e. a cut off point? At the moment I am adjusting the origin.y - Would I have to create a whole new frame which takes into consideration the Y limitation (i.e. the upper bound of the safe area)?

Comment: For matter of practicality, you shouldn't move the root view to account for the keyboard. Instead, you should adjust the size of the scroll view's bottom content inset to at least equal the height of the keyboard. That way, the content itself doesn't move but the user can scroll to the bottom even with the keyboard open.

Comment: I shall try that thank you :)